# How to communicate with 2 devices with 1 UART MCU in AVR

Tags: avr, uart

I am currently looking to integrate `GSM SIM900` and `GPS Module` with `Atmega32`. As atmega32 has 1 UART option, I was just wondering that can I connect these two devices with single UART. I am making a simple GPS tracker which will send a GPS Lats  Longs to user mobile whenever a user ask for it.

Does anyone have any idea about this problem, pls share. Thanks

Comment: Software / bit-bang UART?

Comment: Here is a [question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/183152/make-arduino-and-89c52-talk-to-each-other) with the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't need to communicate with both devices simultaneously, why not use an analog switch (such as the [NLAS4684](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/NLAS4684-D.PDF)) to switch TX / RX between the two devices? Tie the two control inputs together and pass to a spare output on the Atmega32 and you can use one pin to select the device you are communicating with.